# What's the best way to make AJAX calls in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, performance

Include in app/assets/javascripts/*.coffee files ?

Include in *.html.erb file with `<script></script>` ?

Include in partial and render it in view ?

Something else ?

Thank you !

Comment: Your question and description are misleading. Please rectify it.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to compress/minify your js scripts for the pages using them for better performance of your app.

To do this, writing your AJAX server calls on a js file like this `app/assets/custom.js` and including them on your view file with `javascript_include_tag` is the way to go.

write your AJAX script on `app/assets/custom.js`

then include it in your view file

```
= javascript_include_tag "custom.js"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have seen that : http://stackoverflow.com/a/17183769/6430999