# Rails include js into specific view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path, header, ruby-on-rails-5

I know this has been answered here: [Javascript Include Tag Best Practice in a Rails Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390164/javascript-include-tag-best-practice-in-a-rails-application), however I don't get something.

How do I specify what js file is in the :defaults tag? I tried to specify path to js instead of using tag.

In application.html.erb:

```
<head>
  <title>...</title>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  <%= yield :head %>
</head>
```

In view:

```
<% content_for :head, javascript_include_tag('qEditor/http_cdn.quilljs.com_1.3.2_quill') %>
```

This file is in the `app/assets/javascripts/qEditor` and according to IDE the path is correct. I changed the application.js from `//= require_tree .` to `//= require_directory .` so the js file won't be loaded elsewhere. It doesn't work...

Could you help me to solve this? I am really new in rails. Thank you

**UPDATE**

application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>....</title>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= content_for :assets do %>
  <%end%>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
  <%= link_to 'Home', root_path, class: 'btn btn-default' %>
  <button onclick="toggleTodos()" class="btn btn-default">Toggle TODO's</button>

  <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
      <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
  <% end %>


  <div class="jumbotron">
    <%= yield %>
  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could stub the js file to load it manually, then add it to your assets.rb file in the `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile` and then finally add it 
in your view using a `javascript_include_tag`.

Comment: Stubbing is not needed if you place the file in `vendor/assets` where you should be placing vendor content anyways @SebastiánPalma

Comment: I see now, thanks for the tip @max.

Comment: The main problem is that the line in the view is incorrect. Use `content_for` with a block and don't forget to use the `javascript_include_tage` with the `<%=` instead of `<%` tag, otherwise the code will not output in your view. See: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-the-content-for-method

Answer (score 2):

The correct place for vendor content (anything that is not project specific or authored by you) is in `/vendor/assets/javascripts`. This also gets around your problem since `vendor/assets` is not required by `//= require_tree .`.

So move it to `/vendor/assets/javascripts/http_cdn.quilljs.com_1.3.2_quill.js`.

`/vendor/assets` is on Sprockets default assets lookup paths.

```
<head>
  <title>...</title>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= content_for :assets do %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  <% end %>
</head>
```

Since `content_for` concatenates you can just add a `content_for(:assets)` to add additional content:

```
<% content_for :assets do %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag('http_cdn.quilljs.com_1.3.2_quill') %>
<% end %>
```

This also lets you use `provide` or `concat: false` in case you want to overwrite the block provided by the layout.

Comment: I thought it's working, but it isn't... sorry. Could you check my application.html.erb if it's correct?

Comment: ”Its not working” is the most useless information in the world. What specifically is that is not working? You have to debug your application yourself.

Comment: What is not working is that js file isn't loaded in the view. I suspect I don't really understand how should I incoporate "<%= content_for :assets do %>" in application.html.erb because other parts are quite clear.

Comment: Just replace the `<head>` section with the part from my answer. I though that was pretty obvious.